# Bootstrap 4 flex alignment of columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am totally confused. I had this figured out and then refreshed the jsfiddle and somehow the solution changed. I have a row with two columns in the row. I can't get the two columns to align on the same row. I tried using `justify-content-around` and it is not working. Help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-around my-flex-container">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column my-flex-container-column">
      <div class="flex-row my-flex-container">Row 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row my-flex-container">Row 2</div>
      <div class="flex-row my-flex-container">Row 3</div>
      <div class="flex-row my-flex-container">Row 4</div>
    </div>  
    <div class="d-flex flex-column my-flex-container-column">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row my-flex-container">
        <div class="flex-column my-flex-container-column">
           <div class="flex-row my-flex-container">Row 1
           </div>
           <div class="flex-row my-flex-container">Row 2
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-1 my-flex-container">
        <div class="my-auto">ROW 3</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanskene/x1hphsvb/364/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your Bootstrap version from Alpha to Beta release, you can get it [**here**](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css).

```css
  .my-flex-container {
    border: 2px solid green;
  }
   .my-flex-container-column {
    border: 2px solid green;
  }
  .flex-1{
    flex: 1;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-around my-flex-container">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column my-flex-container-column">
      <div class="flex-row my-flex-container">Row 1</div>
      <div class="flex-row my-flex-container">Row 2</div>
      <div class="flex-row my-flex-container">Row 3</div>
      <div class="flex-row my-flex-container">Row 4</div>
    </div>  
    <div class="d-flex flex-column my-flex-container-column">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row my-flex-container">
        <div class="flex-column my-flex-container-column">
           <div class="flex-row my-flex-container">Row 1
           </div>
           <div class="flex-row my-flex-container">Row 2
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-1 my-flex-container">
        <div class="my-auto">ROW 3</div>
      </div>
 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```